# What is the correct/proper way to upload files to a server?

Tags: java, mysql, database

What is the correct/proper way to upload files to a server? I'm only talking about small files such as images, text files, and excel/word files.

I know that I can upload images to the database using BLOB. But what about the others?

I have a table called "Ticket" which contains information such as date created, ticket number, caller, **attachment**, and etc.

I'm having problems on how to upload an **attachment** to a server.

Comment: This is a very broad question and there’s no single correct way. You can use sockets, HTTP, FTP, and many other protocols and ways. It all depends on what exactly you are doing and where you are uploading the files from. How you store it in the end doesn’t really matter, unless I’ve completely misunderstood. Could you clarify exactly what you want to do, meaning upload from where (another machine? User or your application?), what files etc

Comment: Hi @SamiKuhmonen, what I want to do is upload files from another machine using my application. My application can create tickets about incidents. When a user is to create a ticket, they may add attachments to it. What I want to do is similar to transferring a file from computer-1(user) to computer-2(server) to a certain folder given that they are within the same network.

Comment: How do they communicate otherwise? Can that protocol handle files?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen That I don't know yet. Right now I can only describe similar to transferring a file from one computer to another (in a certain folder).

Comment: If there’s no communication between the application and the server now, it’s a bit too early to think of transferring files. First step would be to design the whole communication, of which the files are a part of, but not much of a deciding factor in general. This is way too broad to answer

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Is socket connection a proper way to do it? Where in the server I will create a thread that will wait for any file to be received. Is that even practical?

Answer (score 0):

The first option should be uploading the image to a file server and stored the file id or uuid in your ticket table, or a OneToMany table stores all attachments.

Always void using BLOB to store image binary in database. Database has this capability doesn't mean it's a good way to use it.

If you are working on a small project, you may not see the problem. If the concurrent is relatively high,

Imagine you store the files in the database, even all are just images, whenever you retrieve the tickets, the a-few-MB image will be in the memory. It's a waste of server memory.

If you are using some ORM to retrieve the list, which will be worst and your server can be easily OutOfMemory.

One more thing is that if your system has Web Application Firewall in front, it's also advisable to separate file upload with normal form submission.

Comment: Databases don’t hold data in memory unless it’s used. ORMs don’t load unused data either, unless you tell them to. There are cases when it’s ok to put binaries in the database, others where it’s not, but it’s not always a bad thing. Also what is the last part based on?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Yes, I mean when you are using. If never using, why store in db? For ORM, it's up to which one you use, hibernate will generate wildcard queries default. The last part is based on suggestion from AWS WAF team.

Comment: So it only applies to a very specific use case? Also I didn’t say *never* using. You can query parts of data. You can map parts of data. You can have lazy loading. If one tool does something silly (and I’m pretty sure only when used wrong) it doesn’t mean one shouldn’t store data in a database.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen you can hibernate and see how it works. I am not denying that you can workaround it, but it's just so convenient to use it in that way, even experienced developer. Also, regardless whether you only fetch when you need, the memory use is there. Comparing storing file in a file server or cloud storage, your application use more memory. If concurrently accessing this page, you are at a higher risk to run out of memory.

Comment: You’ll need to show some references to prove that since it definitely doesn’t coincide with reality. Cloud storage has nothing to do with this, nor concurrency.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen the solution you choose will affect your system's scalability.